# Possible VC++17 compiler bug with if constexpr?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, if-constexpr

While playing around with some of the new C++17 features in Visual C++ - I came across an issue which to me seems like a bug.     The code seems to generate as expected when compiling under other compilers using compiler explorer.    The error that is generated :

[Compiler Explorer Link](https://godbolt.org/g/SDTn5X)

Using Visual Studio 2017 15.3.5

```
error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::tuple<unknown-type>'

note: see declaration of 'std::tuple<unknown-type>'

note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void DoSomething<>(void)' being compiled

error C2903: 'remove_reference_t': symbol is neither a class template nor a function template
```

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

struct t_metadata
{
    using type = int;
};


template<typename ...Types>
void DoSomething()
{
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Types) < 1)
    {
        DoSomething<Types..., t_metadata>();
    }
    else
    {
        using T1 = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(std::get<0>(std::tuple<Types...>{}))>;
        typename T1::type tempVal{ };
    }
}

int main()
{
    DoSomething<>();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it's a bug. Please report.